# Cannot find Magick++ header files

Tags: c++, linux, g++, imagemagick, magick++

Hoping someone can help me out as I'm at a complete loss. I've trawled the Internet and really can't find anything more to help me.

I'm trying to compile my c++ program which uses the Magick++ library. I've installed Magick++ seemingly fine. In my current directory is located main.cpp and I'm running `g++ main.cpp`. I'm getting the following error...

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
/home/simeon/ImageMagick-6.8.9-0/Magick++/lib/Magick++.h:9:30: fatal error: Magick++/Include.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

To try and get around the problem I'm declaring the absolute path to Magick++.h in my main.cpp so I have this which seems to be working...

```
#include "/home/simeon/ImageMagick-6.8.9-0/Magick++/lib/Magick++.h"
```

The error occurs on line 9 in Magick++.h (which it's finding due to me absolute path) which looks like this...

```
#include <Magick++/Include.h>
```

This is where I'm confused because this file does exist in the place it says it is. If I run

```
 cat /home/simeon/ImageMagick-6.8.9-0/Magick++/lib/Magick++/Include.h
```

then the file opens without problem and shows its contents.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's going on please? I don't understand why I need to specify an absolute path at all and why g++ isn't finding the header files in the first place. Is there somehow I can tell g++ to look for Magick++ headers in a specific place?

Thanks in advance! 
Simeon

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/ (under the Usage section). It seems like you installed the library manually into your home directory, which isn't right. You should have followed the instructions here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Install.html. That in itself is not the problem, but you need to do that before you can use the instructions in the first link.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are under Linux, I would think you can install the imagemagick package that comes with your installation. It's available on all flavors of Linux I know of.

Under Debian/Ubuntu it would be something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

Otherwise, I personally would use [`cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/) to do all the setup. It's a bit of a learning curve at first, but then it automates those things for you.

It seems to me that if your command line is:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Then you are missing a couple of `-I` options. Installing the package may not require you to use the `-I` option (since I use `cmake` and don't really pay attention to those things... it just works for me.)

So to solve your problem, you probably need something like this:

```
g++ -I/home/simeon/ImageMagick-6.8.9-0/Magick++/lib main.cpp
```

Also, if you have a single `.cpp` file, you may want to use a `-o myprog` command line option.

For the compile and link steps to work as expected, you may want to use the pkgconfig definitions of Magick

```
# compile
pkg-config --cflags /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc

# link
pkg-config --libs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ImageMagick++.pc
```

These commands are actually what `cmake` would try to use to determine the compile time and link time additional flags.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick ships with a configuration utility that should give you the correct path. For Magick++, it's simply `Magick++-config` (see section [Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) in Magick++ docs.)

```bash
IM_CXXFLAGS=$(Magick++-config --cxxflags)
IM_LDFLAGS=$(Magick++-config --ldflags)
g++ $IM_CXXFLAGS $IM_LDFLAGS main.cpp
```

You will need to use the system's include statement (`<>`), and keep it simple by including the parent header.

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need it for single file, here is the proper build command for a Magick++ module:

```
g++ `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` -O2 -Wall -o yourProgramName yourFile.cpp `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

If it does not work you may need to install `libmagick++-dev` first:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev
```

And install imageMagick from Unix Source:

1. download `ImageMagick-7.0.3-5.tar.gz` [from here](http://mirror.checkdomain.de/imagemagick/)
2. Install it using instructions [from here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php)

Comment: Interesting, although on Ubuntu it tells me that the `Magick++-config` tool can be installed with `sudo apt install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat`, which to me makes it sound like it's either deprecated or not expected to be used under Debian/Ubuntu.